# Trying to call amadeus.shopping.flightOffers.get but getting Exception {401}

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, amadeus

I'm in a test environment and I'm trying to make a call to get flights offer with the following line :

```
FlightOffer[] flightsOffer = amadeus.shopping.flightOffers.get(Params
                       .with("originLocationCode", "LON")
                       .and("destinationLocationCode", "FRA")
                       .and("departureDate", "2023-07-15")
                       .and("adults", "2"));
```

But I get an exception with only a number (401) and no message.

I saw that there is an other endpoint named **flightOffersSearch **but i doesn't even appear in my library, in the class Shopping I only see **flightOffers **(i'm correctly using the 2.0.0 version).

Can someone help me ?

Thanks,
Zak

Tried to call flightOffers.get but getting "401" exception without any message.

Comment: A 401 http return code then it means "Unauthorised", so you need to provide some kind of authentication.  Username, password, API Token, etc.  This is missing from your code, so we can't see what you have done wrong.

Comment: As a side-note, I'd be very wary of libraries developed with *no* attention paid to .NET naming conventions, public fields, warnings via console output etc. This screams "not for production use" to me...

Answer (score 1):

The 401 response from an HTTP/HTTPS call means that you are not authorized to access that URL. Generally this means that the API requires some sort of authentication information supplied in the request.

According to [this page](https://developers.amadeus.com/get-started/get-started-with-self-service-apis-335) access to the Amadeus 'Flight Offers' API requires you to register for a token, request a bearer token, then make further requests with that bearer token as the `Authorization` header. The basic process is detailed on that page in the "Step 3: Calling the API" section.

I've never used the API, but it looks fairly straighforward.